# Child elements not found in page object after adding them in the html in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer-11

I have in my program a loop that prints a structure like this in each iteration:

```
<div class="grand-father">
  <div class = "father">
    <myTag>1</myTag>
    <button>show more</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

But after clicking the button the structure changes to:

```
<div class="grand-father">
  <div class = "father">
    <myTag>1</myTag>
    <myTag>2</myTag>
    <myTag>3</myTag>
  </div>
</div>
```

So in my tests with page object model I'm trying to evaluate every *myTag* element in each "grand-father" element by doing:

```
List<WebElement> grandFathers = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='grand-father']"));
for(WebElement gf : grandFathers){
  //**Click the button of this father element to show more**
  List<WebElement> myTagElements = gf.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='father']/myTag"));
  System.out.println(myTagElements.size());
}
```

My problem is that the last findElements for the myTag elements doesn't seem to be finding all the elements that weren't there before the "show more" button was pressed :( it's only counting one element even though all elements are already shown :/

Is there any way to tell selenium to "update" the variable according to the new html changes that weren't there when we first fetched the element? (Because I think that the problem might be that one)

Thanks if anyone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may have the answer already but for future readers, I would do something like this...

Grab all the `DIV`s with the class `grand-father` and loop through them looking for child `BUTTON`s. Click the `BUTTON` and then count the `myTag`s.

```
List<WebElement> gfs = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.grand-father"));
for (WebElement gf : gfs)
{
    gf.findElement(By.tagName("button")).click();
    System.out.println(gf.findElements(By.tagName("myTag")).size());
}
```

Comment: that's great man! That's what I did :D Thanks for a more elaborate answer

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by refactoring all the code and clicking the "Show More" button when using findElements for the "father" elements, waay before using the findElements method for the *myTag* elements. 
Keep this in mind when dealing with elements that will eventually show up in your DOM: First make all the operations that involve showing and processing data, then use Selenium to evaluate them :)